# when i run migrate the uuid is field is updating always will it give me some perfomance issue is anyone can explain me the reason and solution

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    activate_token = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=str(uuid.uuid4()))
    forget_password_token = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=str(uuid.uuid4()))
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)    


Accounts\migrations\0010_alter_customer_activate_token_and_more.py
        - Alter field activate_token on customer
        - Alter field forget_password_token on customer
    Migrations for 'Store':
      Store\migrations\0004_product_shipping_charges_alter_product_price.py
        - Add field shipping_charges to product
        - Alter field price on product
```

I have a model of customer i am storeing two things there one is user activation token and the other is  forgot password token i want it random so i used uuid but when ever i am running migrate this migration always happening by the way i am not facing any functional error everything working fine but i have a feeling it might give me a error

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the uuid4 function call with the callable (that is, without brackets) and Django will know that the uuid is meant to remain constant.

```
forget_password_token = models.CharField(max_length=200,default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Comment: that does not work brother

Comment: @sarangkkl, please remove the str() function around uuid.uuid4 and make sure uuid is imported.